# apt command missing in cloud image of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I spun up a VM based of ubuntu18.04 cloudinit image(ubuntu-18.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.vmdk) and I do not see apt command in it. How do I install apt on to this ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any *official* Ubuntu images that do not include `apt` so I'd ensure you're using an official image and that it doesn't contain other *surprises* that could lead to assumptions & problems later on.  If you want to use your image, you need to download (`wget` etc) and install apt (`dpkg`)  (`apt-get` is likely also missing; as it's contained in the same package.. but I'd consider exploring your image to actually work out what you have, what's been done to it!

Comment: That particular cloud image should indeed have apt. Nobody has reported a bug about apt missing from it.